# Parse JSON and bind to dynamically created rows and columns of HTML table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Using angularjs here:

I have a HTML table whose columns and editable rows are dynamically created. User can save this details in the db.

Being dynamically created I am saving the columns names as comma separated names. The rows are also saved as comma separated values for each row.

For example db table as below:

```
Id col                      row       comment   createdby
1  col1, col2, col3, col4   1,2,3,4   test1     abc
2  col1, col2, col3, col4   5,6,7,8   test2     abc
```

During the details view user I want to redraw the table fetching the col and row values from the database as below

The above table would look like as below on the UI

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
 1    2    3    4
 5    6    7    8
```

Code for table is as below:

```
function createTable() {   
   return {      
     columns: [],
     rows: [{}]     
        }
   }

 var table = {
       columns: [],
       rows: [{}]
    };              
$scope.tables = [table];
$scope.tables.push(createTable());
$scope.targetTable = $scope.tables[0];
```

Json returned from my api is something like this:

```
{
  colName: "col1, col2, col3, col4
  rowValues: "1,2,3,4"
}
{
  colName: "col1, col2, col3, col4
  rowValues: "5,6,7,8"
}
//and so on we can have more rows
```

For columns I do this.

```
var colArray = json.colName.split(',');
for (var i = 0; i < colArray.length; i++) {
$scope.targetTable.columns.push({       
    colName: colJson.col.split(',')[i],      
//where colName is the ng-model in the html for table header
});
}
```

The above code works fine and I can see my HTML table created with all these columns

What I am having hard time to find a solution to bind my rows to this table since they are dynamically created and dont have limit to no of rows.

For adding rows we would do

```
  $scope.targetTable.rows.push({});
```

So in my case how can I loop through  my Json and push each value to the row.
For ex something like this would create a first two rows as per my json:

```
 $scope.targetTable.rows.push({
        "0":"1", "1":"2", "2":"3","3":"4"
});
 $scope.targetTable.rows.push({
        "0":"5", "1":"6", "2":"7","3":"8"
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if this solution will answer your question, if not, I'll try to update it as needed.

For a single row, I believe this method will work as intended:

```
var rowArray = json.rowValues.split(',');
for (var i = 0; i < rowArray.length; i++) {
    var rowObject = {};
    json.rowValues.split(',').forEach((elem, index) => {
        rowObject[index] = elem;
    })

    $scope.targetTable.rows.push(rowObject);
}
```

This will take a row from `json.rowValues`, which is formatted like `11,22,33,44`, and tranform it into an object which matches your row format (`{0: "11", 1: "22", 2: "33", 3: "44"}`). This object is then pushed to your table in $scope.

Comment: The above would work for just one row. Again being issue here is that I have array of json if you see my post above. I need to parse that json row array and then fit your solution to that. What I am expecting is the above function to be called twice creating 2 rows. One for {0: "1", 1: "2", 2: "3", 3: "4"} and second one for  {0: "5", 1: "6", 2: "7", 3: "8"}

Comment: Ah, I didn’t realize that the JSON is returned in an array as it’s not formatted like an array. I’ve updated my answer with code that should work for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this.

```
// New data that you will push
newJson = {}; 

// The data you pulled from server
oldJson = { 
  colName: "col1, col2, col3, col4",
  rowValues: "1,2,3,4",
};


oldJson.rowValues.split(',').map((element, index) => {
    newJson[index] = element;
});
// New Json... Expected Output: {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4}

$scope.targetTable.rows.push(newJson);
```

Comment: As I posted in the previous comment. This works for single row. I have json array of rows. How can I loop through json array and then use your above logic

Comment: You would need to save the JSON you are getting from your api as an array. Example: `{
 "Rows": [{
   "colName": "col1, col2, col3, col4",
   "rowValues": "1,2,3,4"
  },
  {
   "colName": "col1, col2, col3, col4",
   "rowValues": "5,6,7,8"
  }
 ]
}` Then you should be able to iterate over each element of Rows using the previously mentioned function.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using jQuery. you can compose table structure and append to table-body, e.g.,

> "yourdata": {   colName: "col1, col2, col3, col4   rowValues:
>   "1,2,3,4" } {   colName: "col1, col2, col3, col4   rowValues:
>   "5,6,7,8" }

```
$.getJSON("your-restapi/ or x.php" + function (data) {

 $.each(data.yourdata, function() {
    $.each(this, function(k, v) {
          $('<tr>' +
                '<td>' + v.rowValues + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + v.colName + '</td>' +
              </tr>').appendTo("table-body");
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: This question is very specifically about AngularJs.  Using JQuery with AngularJs is  not recommended, and an answer suggesting to use JQuery instead of AngularJs really misses the point of the question.